# put request returning 401

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm new to django/tastypie. I've built an api and have get requests working fine but every time I run a post/put request I'm getting a 401.

This is my api:

```
class CategoryResource(ModelResource):
class Meta:
   queryset = Category.objects.all() 
   resources_name = 'category'
   Authorization=Authorization()
   allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put']
```

And this is my test:

```
def test_update_user_score(self):
    response = self.c.put('/api/v1/category/', {'apikey': 1})
    print response.status_code
```

any ideas greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 401 deals with Authorization problems.
I dont know if there is another problem with your code, but I can see a typo here:

```
Authorization=Authorization()
```

must be:

```
authorization=Authorization()
```

with lowercase 'a'.
Let us know if this solved your problem and assign points if helpful.
Best Wishes.

Comment: Thanks, silly mistake. Now instead of a 401 I'm getting a 500 though

Comment: As I can see you are trying to access tastypie resources inside a view function. Here is how to do it: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#using-your-resource-in-regular-views  although I thing it is easier to test with the help of a browser.